# find -exec unzip multiple .zip files, each into their own directory where source and destination different

Tags: linux

I have a directory that new `.zip` files get placed every day. I need to find new files within the last day, and unzip the files each into their own directory in a different location.  What I have found with a lot of searching almost does this for me.

```
find /source1/source2/source3 -maxdepth 1 -type f -mtime -1 \
    -exec sh -c 'unzip -d /dest1/dest2/"${1%.*}" "$1"' _ {}
```

The problem with the above line, is the destination directory it is trying to create is `/dest1/dest2/source1/source2/source3/(dir that is the filename of the zip)/{unzipped files}`  I need it to just be `/dest1/dest2/{filename}`

Is there a way to strip the source directories out of the `${1%.*}` variable?  Or if there is a better way to get this done i'm open to any suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can strip the source directories with `basename`. Just replace `"${1%.*}"` with `$(basename "${1%.*}")`.

Comment: that got a step closer, but in the destination folder, i need each zip to unzip to its own folder.  the above worked, but it dumped all zips into the same folder.

Comment: What's the name of the folder all files got dumped in, and what name should it have instead?

Comment: i should have specified better in the original question, i need the destination to be /dest1/dest2/(dir that is the filename of the zip)/{unzipped files}

Comment: `basename` should just give you the filename of the zip without path and without extension.

Comment: Do you want one directory for each zip file or one directory for each of the files inside of your zip file?

Comment: it needs to be a directory for each zip file, as each zip file has a few .PDF files in it, and some of the .PDF files have the same name

Comment: i got it to work with /dest1/des2/$(basename "$1") "$1" _ {}  it keeps the .zip in the directory name, but that doesn't matter to me.

Comment: @Sanren ... _"i should have specified better in the original question"_ — then you should edit the question _now_ to say that.